# How to detect the digit area in binary image

Tags: c++, opencv

I have images as the below, how to only detect the digit area. I used to bounding- contours to detect digit, but I don't know to delete the area without is digit.

[image: Binary image1]

Comment: Which language, C **or** C++?  They are different, for example, C++ has iterators and `std::vector`.  In the C language, I can have a variable called "class".  Please edit your tags accordingly.

Comment: More importantly, OpenCV has different C and C++ API's.

Comment: Check out the binary image library. https://github.com/MalcolmMcLean/binaryimagelibrary You can easily query images for sub-images, do floodfills, etc

Comment: @Malcolm McLean thanks so much for the help

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to look the code at [this repository](https://github.com/sturkmen72/OpenCV_3_KNN_Character_Recognition_Cpp)

by using it you will get a result image like below.
[image]

[image]